# Variable scope outside Nested Loop c++

Tags: c++

For variable: X below, I can print in case1, but why can't I print value X in case2 ?

```
std::vector<double> X;
double a = -1;

for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){

        double b = 0; 
        if(a <0){
            b = a + i*i - 100;
        } 
        if(b > 0){
            X.push_back(b);
        }

    }
std::cout << "case1:" << X.size() << std::endl;
}

std::cout << "case2:" << X.size() << std::endl;
```

Comment: X.size() doesn't return some integer?

Comment: does this even compile?

Comment: Ignoring the fact that `b` falls out of scope and the code won't compile, what is the purpose of this function? You will simply end up with a `m` x `n` 1D vector of `-1` since `a` is never modified. Also you are adding `int` values into a vector of `double` you should probably pick one.

Comment: This is just an example. The size can return value outside first for loop. But doesn't work in this case. I don't know why.

Comment: @user3384116 _'But doesn't work in this case'_ What exactly doesn't work, you are too vague!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable b exists only in the compound statement of the if statement

```
    if(a < 0){

        int b = a;
    }
```

The compiler shall issue an error for the second if statement

```
    if(b != 0){

        X.push_back(b);
    }
```

because name b is undefined in this declarative region.

You could rewrite your code snippet the following way

```
std::vector<double> X;
int a = -1;

for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){

        int b = 0;

        if(a < 0){

            b = a;
        }
        if(b != 0){

            X.push_back(b);
        }

    }
}

std::cout << X.size();
```

that it would be at least compiled

If you will try this code then the size of  the vector will be outputed provided that all variavles arre properly declared and initialized (including m and n).

Comment: Ignoring the a,b variable. See X. Why can I print it outside first for loop. But not work outside second for loop.

Comment: @user3384116 Se my updated post.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `b` only exists inside of the `if()` statement it is created in. Therefore, when you try to push it onto the vector it is out of scope and you no longer have access to it. If you would like to do the same thing, just move `int b` up above the `if()` statements but still inside the loops.